A smarter way to "offset" an element from its container (with background)?
I've got to do a layout like this:

As you can see, the hero image is 'offsetted', background being shorter of it.
I managed to do it with nested css grids and a 'dummy' element to add background, but I was wondering if there are smarter ways than using a dummy element...
I'm posting a codepen because this built-in editor seems not to correctly render the code I used. I commented it all to explain the important bits.
https://codepen.io/stratboy/pen/YzbbXVa
I'm forced by Stackoverflow to write some code.. Here is some HTML:
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="bg">
    </div>
    <div class="child">
      <div class="offset image">offset</div>
      <div class="text">Lorem Ipsum</div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

And (S)CSS:
    .wrapper{ // just to simulate real website
      width: 1200px;
      margin: 0 auto;
    }
    
    .container{ // main grid
      display: grid;
      grid-template-rows: 80px auto 120px;
      grid-template-columns: 1fr;
    
      // full width
      margin-left: calc(-50vw + 50%);
      margin-right: calc(-50vw + 50%);
    }
    
    .bg{ // dummy element  for background
      background-color: teal;
      grid-row: 1 / 3;
      grid-column: 1 / 2;
    }
    
    .child{  
      width: 1200px;
      margin: 0 auto;
      grid-row: 2 / 4; // offset for simulated padding
      grid-column: 1 / 2;
      
      display: grid; // it is a grid itself, so I can offset the "image"
      grid-template-rows: 1fr 120px;
      grid-template-columns: 50% 50%;
    }
    
    .offset.image{
      grid-column: 1 / 2;
      grid-row: 1 / 3;
      background-color: cyan;
    }
    
    .text{
      grid-column: 2 / 3; // restrict to first 2 rows to create the image offset
      grid-row: 1 / 2;
      background-color: green;
      padding-bottom: 80px; // just to test
    }



comments with // are invalid in CSS, you have to use /* */

Just use a linear-gradient that stops a certain distance from the bottom of the containing element.


* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

div {
  height: 90vh;
  padding: 20px;
  background-image: 
  linear-gradient(to bottom, pink calc(100% - 50px), transparent calc(100% - 50px));
}

img {
  height: 100%;
  width: auto;
}
<div>
  <img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1717496001989-0a0f32386d12?crop=entropy&cs=srgb&fm=jpg&ixid=M3wzMjM4NDZ8MHwxfHJhbmRvbXx8fHx8fHx8fDE3MTk1NzU3MzR8&ixlib=rb-4.0.3&q=85" alt="">
</div>




Here is another approach by using transforms, some (basic) calculations and a negative margin. Also fully responsive.


section {
  /* define your desired paddings */
  --h-padding: 2rem;
  --v-padding: 2rem;
  /* define your desired offset for this section */
  --offset: 3rem;
}

section .inner {
  background: teal;
  padding: var(--v-padding) var(--h-padding);
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr;
  gap: 2rem;
}

.hero img {
  vertical-align: top;
  object-fit: cover;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

@media screen and (min-width: 80ch) {
  section {
    /* add offset to bottom padding to extend the box model -  this prevents overlapping with following elements */
    padding-bottom: var(--offset);
  }
  section .inner {
    grid-template-columns: 2fr 1fr;
    gap: 4rem;
  }
  .hero {
    /* pull hero container up */
    margin-top: calc((var(--offset) + var(--v-padding)) * -1);
  }
  .hero img {
    /* move your image down by applying the offset transform */
    transform: translateY(calc(var(--offset) + var(--v-padding)));
  }
}


/* demo css */

html {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

*,
*::after,
*::before {
  box-sizing: inherit;
}

.content p:first-child {
  margin-top: 0;
}
<section>
  <div class="inner">
    <div class="hero">
      <img src="https://picsum.photos/800/450" alt="heroimage" />
    </div>
    <div class="content">
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Etiam orci ex, ullamcorper id ultrices vel, lacinia ut elit. Maecenas at justo a mauris cursus</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</section>




Could you just use a pseudo element to provide a background that only extends down as far as the overhang? That's the simplest way I can think of


.content {
  position: relative;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 2fr 1fr;
  --overhang: 2rem;
}

.content::after {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  inset: 0 0 var(--overhang) 0;
  background-color: #F0EEE9;
  z-index: 2;
}

.text, .image {
  z-index: 3;
  padding: 0.5rem;
}

.text {
  padding-bottom: var(--overhang); /* just make sure the text doesn't encroach over the overhung region */
}
<div class="content">
  <div class="image">
    <img src='https://picsum.photos/id/237/300/200'>
  </div>
  <div class="text">
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Etiam orci ex, ullamcorper id ultrices vel, lacinia ut elit. Maecenas at justo a mauris cursus
  </div>
</div>




As this post shows, there are soooo many ways to do such things with CSS. There is no best solutions but some may fit your needs best
Some solutions could be background-image, clip-path, complex grids, overflow, absolute/relative positioning, gradient background...
Here's an example using simple overflow, the downside is that you'll need some kind of margin for the elements below.


.fake-image {
  width: 200px;
  margin-top: 3rem;
  aspect-ratio: 2;
  background: red;
}

.grid {
  justify-items: center;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 50% 50%;
  grid-template-rows: 10rem;
  background-color: pink;
  overflow: visible /* not needed */
}
  
<div class="grid">
  <div class="fake-image"></div>
  <div>
    <h3>page title</h3>
    <p> Some longer content </p>
  </div>
</div>
<div>
  Here is some text that wil appear under the picture
</div>



